# Evaluating a variant of the polylogarithm

Tags: power-series, special-functions, polylogarithm

Consider the infinite sum : 
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\binom{m}{my}\frac{z^{m}}{m^{s}}\;\;\;\;s\in\mathbb{C},\;\;\;\;|z|<\frac{1}{2},\;\;\;\;\;0<y<1$$
I want to evaluate this summation in terms of special functions. It looks tantalizingly like the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) function. I tried using integral representations of the binomial coefficient, but to no avail. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Con you provide som more context? Where does this sum arise? How did you get the bounds on the variables? [wolfram alpha tells me that for $y=1/2$, it only converges if $|z|<1/2$.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+m%21%2F%28%28m%2F2%29%21%28m-%28m%2F2%29%29%21%29+z%5Em%2Fm%5Es%2C+m%3D1+to+infinity)

Comment: That's right, it should be $|z|<0.5$. corrected.

Comment: Still some context would be nice.

Comment: This summation came up in the study of Dirichlet series of the form $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_{m}\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^{m}\binom{m}{j}\frac{b_{j}}{(j+1)^{z}}$. where the generating Dirichlet series of $b_{j}$, and the ordinary generating function of $a_{m}$ are known. You can easily verify that $\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^{m}\binom{m}{j}\frac{b_{j}}{(j+1)^{z}}=\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{\Re(s)=\alpha}B(s)G_{m}(s,z)ds$. where $B(s)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{b_{k}}{k^{s}}$, and $G_{m}(s,z)=\int_{0}^{m}(-1)^{x}\binom{m}{x}\frac{x^{s-1}}{(1+x)^{z}}dx$.

Comment: The infinite sum in my thread sort of gets you halfway in finding $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_{m} G_{m}(s,z)$